# Tracing an executable file compiled in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt, dll

How can we trace a compiled application from windows 7. I can see in the event viewer that some DLL files which my program is trying to fetch are causing problems but I can't figure out why.(This is with qtcored4.dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve DLL loading problems with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), either by looking at the exe (just open it) or tracing DLL load process by starting profile.